# AG Grid not displaying all values in React

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have an AG Grid table where some values are not being displayed in the cells. The data/values in the cells are being filled by 3 API calls. So like I call 1 API and from the response of that one, I can call the other 2. From the other 2 I just add needed info/data to the 1st API response object.

So what happens in the table at first, some fields have missing data although I noticed there is commas where the values should be. Then I noticed from scrolling all the way to the right and then back to the left, the data in the cells appear. Weird! Currently using a `valueGetter` attribute with anonymous function to display the data that is missing. Not sure if `cellRender` or something else would be better.

```
{
      headerName: 'Current Best Purchase Price',
      resizable: true,
      wrapHeaderText: true,
      width: 150,
      valueGetter: (params) => {
        return params.data.productIdentifiers.assets.map((item) => {
          return item.currentBestPurchasePrice;
        });
      },
    },
```

See picture links

[image: After hitting the submit button]

[image: Scrolling all the way to the right, then scrolling back to the left]

Bonus points. I am also trying to display values in the cells as something like this for some:

| Current Best Purchase Price |
| --- |
| $28.99 |
| $25.99 |
| $23.99 |

I have tried using a `cellStyle` and setting `white-space: pre-wrap`.

Answer (score 0):

Figure out the bonus pts part. Ex:

```
{
      headerName: 'Current Best Purchase Price',
      resizable: true,
      wrapHeaderText: true,
      width: 150,
      cellStyle: { 'white-space': 'pre-wrap' },
      valueGetter: (params) => {
        return params.data.productIdentifiers.assets
          .map((item) => {
            return item.currentBestPurchasePrice;
          })
          .toString()
          .split(',')
          .join('\n')
          .trim();
      },
    },
```